# Error in Image crop using MiniMagick with carreirwave in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, crop, minimagick

I am trying to crop image using mini magick gem with carrierwave. I am facing following issue when i am creating user.

```
Errno::ENOENT in UsersController#create

No such file or directory - identify -ping /tmp/mini_magick20120919-5600-ai31ph.jpg
```

My Code :
model/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_h, :crop_w
    attr_accessible :username,:profile
  after_update :reprocess_profile, :if => :cropping?

  #field :username

  mount_uploader :profile, ProfileUploader

  def cropping?
    !crop_x.blank? and !crop_y.blank? and !crop_h.blank? and !crop_w.blank?
  end

  def profile_geometry
    #img = MiniMagick::Image.open(self.profile.large.path)
    #@geometry = {:width => img[:width], :height => img[:height] }
  end

  private

  def reprocess_profile
    #puts self.profile.large.path
    #img = MiniMagick::Image.open(self.profile.large.path)
    #crop_params = "#{crop_w}x#{crop_h}+#{crop_x}+#{crop_y}"
    #img.crop(crop_params)
    #img.write(self.profile.path)
    #profile.recreate_versions!
  end

end
```

uploader/profile_uploader.rb

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ProfileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or ImageScience support:
  #include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::ImageScience
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  version :large do
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [100, 100]
  end

end
```

What would be the problem ? please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to install imagemagick.
In ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```